# Problem with sitemap generation in Gatsby js

Tags: javascript, gatsby, sitemap

I'm having a problem with creating a sitemap for my website.
this is gatsby-config.js content :

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: `https://www.mywebsite.com`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
      options: {
        excludes: [],
        query: `
        {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              siteUrl
            }
          }
          allSitePage {
           nodes {
             path
           }
          }
      }`,
        serialize : ({site,allSitePage}) =>
             allSitePage.nodes.map(node => { // this is line 32
                return {
                  url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${node.path}`,
                  changefreq: `never`,
                  priority: 0.5,
                }
              })
          },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

I get this error when I want to build the project :

[image]

note: when I don't add options like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: `https://www.mywebsite.com`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

everything works fine but it does not meet my needs (all pages have the same priority 0.7)

---

**Solved! this code does not work with versions above 3.3.0 so I downgraded the sitemap plugin from 4.9.0 to 3.3.0 and now works like a charm.**

Comment: Is your query fetching the proper results in the GraphiQL playground? (`localhost:8000/___graphql`)

Comment: @Ferran, yes the above query works fine and fetch data in graphQL playground but it says allSitePage is undefined in production, I tried replacing nodes{path} by edges {node{path}} but other errors occurred

Comment: Solved! this code does not work with versions above 3.3.0 so I **downgraded** the sitemap plugin from 4.9.0 to **3.3.0** and now works like a charm. thank you @Ferran for your try : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/v/3.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may be facing the issue: It as been solved by downgrading the plugin to the 3.3.0 version prior to the 4.9.0 (the one causing the issue).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/v/3.3.0